# App crashes with error when I use data binding in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have adapter:

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int CATEGORY    = 0;

    public static final int ITEM        = 1;

    public static final int LOADING     = 2;

    protected List<Record> mRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<OnItemClickListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<>(1);
    private List<OnLoadMoreListener> mLoadMoreListeners = new ArrayList<>(1);
    private boolean mIsEndlessMode = false;
    private boolean mIsLoading = false;
    private int mVisibleThreshold = 2;
    private int mLastVisibleItem;
    private int mTotalItemCount;
    private ColorDrawable mStub;

    public DetailsAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        mStub = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(recyclerView.getContext(),
                android.R.color.transparent));

        if(manager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            final LinearLayoutManager lm = (LinearLayoutManager)manager;
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    mTotalItemCount = lm.getItemCount();
                    mLastVisibleItem = lm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (mIsEndlessMode && !mIsLoading
                            && mTotalItemCount <= (mLastVisibleItem + mVisibleThreshold)) {
                        // End has been reached
                        // Do something
                        for(OnLoadMoreListener l : mLoadMoreListeners) {
                            l.onLoadMore();
                        }

                        mIsLoading = true;
                        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                notifyItemInserted(mRecords.size());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {

        if(position >= mRecords.size()) {
            return LOADING;
        }

        return mRecords.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {

        if(position >= mRecords.size()) {
            return -1;
        }

        return mRecords.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        if(viewType == ITEM) {
            LiDetailsSimpleBinding binding = LiDetailsSimpleBinding.inflate(i, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(binding.getRoot());
        } else if(viewType == CATEGORY) {
            return new CategoryViewHolder(i.inflate(R.layout.li_details_category, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new LoadingViewHolder(i.inflate(R.layout.li_details_loading, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(position >= mRecords.size()) {
            return;
        }

        Record record = mRecords.get(position);

        if(record.mType == ITEM) {
            ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder)holder;
            Item item = (Item) record;

            if(item.getAction() == null) {
                item.setAction(mStub);
                itemHolder.mBinding.setActionVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                itemHolder.mBinding.setActionVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if(item.getIcon() == null) {
                item.setIcon(mStub);
                itemHolder.mBinding.setIconVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                itemHolder.mBinding.setIconVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            itemHolder.mBinding.setItem(item);
        } else {
            ((CategoryViewHolder)holder).mText1.setText(record.getTitle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mIsEndlessMode && mIsLoading ? mRecords.size() + 1 : mRecords.size();
    }

    public class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView mText1;

        public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mText1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            itemView.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected LiDetailsSimpleBinding mBinding;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(OnItemClickListener l : mListeners) {
                        l.onItemClick(v, ClickType.ITEM, getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class Record implements Parcelable {

        private long mId = RecyclerView.NO_ID;
        private String mTitle;
        protected int mType;

        public Record(final long id, final String title) {
            mId = id;
            mTitle = ObjectsCompat.requireNotNull(title, "Title must be not null!");
        }

        protected Record(Parcel in) {
            mId = in.readLong();
            mTitle = in.readString();
            mType = in.readInt();
        }

        public static final Creator<Record> CREATOR = new Creator<Record>() {
            @Override
            public Record createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Record(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Record[] newArray(final int size) {
                return new Record[size];
            }
        };

        public void setId(final long id) {
            mId = id;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return mType;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(final String title) {
            mTitle = ObjectsCompat.requireNotNull(title, "Title must be not null!");
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, final int flags) {
            dest.writeLong(mId);
            dest.writeString(mTitle);
            dest.writeInt(mType);
        }
    }

    public static class Category extends  Record {

        public Category(long id, String title) {
            super(id, title);
            mType = CATEGORY;
        }

        public Category(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
        }

        public static final Creator<Category> CREATOR = new Creator<Category>() {
            @Override
            public Category createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Category(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Category[] newArray(final int size) {
                return new Category[size];
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Item extends Record {

        private String mSubtitle;
        private Drawable mIcon = null;
        private Drawable mAction;

        public Item(final long id, @Nullable Drawable icon, final String title,
                    @Nullable final String subtitle) {
            super(id, title);
            mIcon = icon;
            mSubtitle = subtitle;
            mType = ITEM;
        }

        public Item(@Nullable Drawable icon, final String title, @Nullable final String subtitle) {
            this(RecyclerView.NO_ID, icon, title, subtitle);
        }

        public Item(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            mSubtitle = in.readString();
            final int isIcon = in.readInt();
            final int isAction = in.readInt();
            Resources res = Resources.getSystem();

            if(isIcon == 1) {
                Bitmap icon = in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
                mIcon = new BitmapDrawable(res, icon);
            }

            if(isAction == 1) {
                Bitmap action = in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
                mAction = new BitmapDrawable(res, action);
            }
        }

        public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Item(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Item[] newArray(final int size) {
                return new Item[size];
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, final int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeString(mSubtitle);
            dest.writeInt(mIcon == null ? 0 : 1);
            dest.writeInt(mAction == null ? 0 : 1);

            if(mIcon != null) {
                Bitmap icon = ((BitmapDrawable) mIcon).getBitmap();
                dest.writeParcelable(icon, flags);
            }

            if(mAction != null) {
                Bitmap action = ((BitmapDrawable) mAction).getBitmap();
                dest.writeParcelable(action, flags);
            }
        }

        public String getSubtitle() {
            return mSubtitle;
        }

        public void setSubtitle(@Nullable String subtitle) {
            mSubtitle = subtitle;
        }

        public Drawable getIcon() {
            return mIcon;
        }

        public void setIcon(@Nullable Drawable icon) {
            mIcon = icon;
        }

        public Drawable getAction() {
            return mAction;
        }

        public void setAction(@Nullable Drawable action) {
            mAction = action;
        }
    }
}
```

And xml for binding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable"/>

        <variable name="item" type="com.mycompany.myapp.utils.adapter.DetailsAdapter.Item"/>
        <variable name="iconVisibility" type="int" />
        <variable name="actionVisibility" type="int" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:visibility="@{iconVisibility}"
            android:src="@{item.getIcon()}" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="@{actionVisibility}"
            android:src="@{item.getAction()}" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/action"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/action"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black_87"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@{item.getTitle()}"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web|email"
                android:linksClickable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black_54"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@{item.getSubtitle()}"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

But it outputs error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{e774c66 position=6 id=-1, oldPos=5, pLpos:5 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4618) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:2954) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2879) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3265) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122) 
    at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42) 
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1149) 
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
```

P.S. I only start to switch to the data binding. And cannot understand a bug reason. I haven't this bug without using of the data binding.

Comment: Take a look at your getCount() method, you are returning a number larger than the amount of items available hence IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I return size more than records when I enable loading mode. Then adapter returns LOADING type at last position (it equals record size) and creates `LoadingViewHolder` after in `onBindViewHolder` it just returns because `RecyclerView` shows simple loading without some data in this item.